# VBscript alternatives to writing variables to a file needed (FSO.write is too slow)

Tags: vbscript

**TL;DR: I need something way faster than FSO.write OR another way to share a variable in memory between different script instances.**

Hello, I am running CCPulse (on Windows 7), which is a Call Center monitoring tool. Agents are represented as "Objects" and can have various statistics (like calls taken, total talk duration etc). CCPulse allows to apply thresholds and actions to any statistic. These are basically vbscripts and as far as I can tell, there are no restrictions.

This allows me to take the "Threshold StatValue" and do things with it, ie writing it to a file. The issue is that if I apply a threshold to a statistic for all agents, the script executes for each agent object seperately (in sequence, not parallel). However, I want to export all the agent stats to a single csv file.

I already got it working, by creating a file if it doesn't exist, then open/ReadAll into a string. If an agent has not been written to the file yet his stat values get appended as a newline in the string, if he already exists in this file I search and replace his line using a regex pattern. I then write the entire multiline string back to the file:

```
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(inFile,2)
objFile.Write strMemoryBuffer
objFile.Close 
set objFile = nothing
```

strMemoryBuffer contains the files original content, with either a new line or a modified line. This string (and subsequently the export file) is around 30kb in size after all agents have been exported. It looks like this (simplified):

```
LoginID;Calls;TotalTalkTime
2243;08;9403
2132;12;8439
```

As I said, since the script runs seperately for each agent, only one line is ever added/modified per pass (CCpulse will execute the script one object at a time, until all are finished).

The write process is very slow however, using Timer() it says it needs between 0.10 and 0.15 seconds! That is way too slow, as I need to run the script on almost 500 agents (ideally in no more than 30 second intervals), but all the writing would take over a minute (CCPulse would create a backlog of threshold operations which could never be finished. I can decrease the recalculation frequency, but that is detrimental in other ways).

If I comment out only the above block, execution time dramatically decreases to ~0.02 seconds. So reading the file and manipulating the string takes almost no time at all, just the write process is slow.

I am writing the file locally to a hard drive (no SSD though). I cannot use a RAM Disk.

I also already tried writing to the volatile environment, but somehow, this is even slower (it does work, but for some reason the explorer process goes crazy with up to 50% cpu usage and ccpulse locks up, allthough the export file is still being updated).

The ideal solution would to have the string being repeadetly manipulated only in memory, and then written to file like only once every 30 seconds or something like that, but I don't know how I can make the strMemoryBuffer variable available to the "next" agent. Any ideas?

Comment: I found the solution myself just now. Exporting to volatile environment was slow because it's stored in the registry. However, exporting to process environment yields the desired result and is super fast:

`Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set env = sh.Environment("PROCESS")`

And then later instead of writing to file: 
`env("strMemoryBuffer") = strMemoryBuffer'

Comment: Please write your solution as an answer instead of as a comment. It is perfectly acceptable to self-answer your question here on StackOverflow.